# Is "The State it was In when it was..." too wordy?

Tags: grammar, redundancy, construction

I saw this message:

> Reset all save data and return the game to the state it was in when it was newly purchased

Is the `the state it was in` too wordy or redundant? Can it be just `the state when it was newly purchased`? Which grammar rule am I breaking if it were the later?

Comment: "the state **it was when** newly purchased."

Comment: "return the game to its **initial configuration**" ...or... "reset the game", "reset the game to its defaults", or "clear all data and return the game in its original condition". And if none of those work... "Return the game to its factory settings."

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. however, if the sentence isn't technically wrong, then we'll just leave it in our product. I was also just curious if it was too wordy, and why `it was in` was necessary

Comment: @Devmonster The sentence is perfectly grammatical. At least it sounds that way to me.Happy hacking. :)

Comment: For better fluency I would probably use _...and return the game to its original state._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current English idiom allows even more compression:

*"return the game to the **state when newly purchased**"*

eventually punctuated:

*"return the game to the **state-when-newly-purchased**"*

See:

> [Technical studies.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9iSp_CEOHjsC&q=%22the%20state%20when%20newly%22&dq=%22the%20state%20when%20newly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=16ATVebXA5TjoASwmYHYBA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAw) - Page 176 Douglas F. Greer, ‎United States.
>   National Commission on Consumer Finance, ‎Robert Paul Shay - 1974
>
> ... as a measure of the average quality of cars in the state **when
>   newly purchased**. Its expected sign is of course positive, and it is
>   intended as a variable which could represent those factors influencing
>   quality demand which are not accounted for by the other included
>   variables.

or:

> [Identity, Consciousness and Value](https://books.google.ca/books?id=mkSmvSfRsOsC&pg=PA120&dq=%22to%20its%20state%20when%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GqQTVbTXFMnSoATrroGIDQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20its%20state%20when%22&f=false) - Page 120 Peter Unger
>   Professor of Philosophy New York University - 1990
>
> When an adequate cure for the illness is discovered, the person's
>   body, including her brain, is instantaneously unfrozen, or thawed; it
>   is thus returned to **its state when last alive**.